# SQL joining huge tables by excluding just one column in select statement

Tags: sql, select, join

I have three huge tables each with many many columns (say 500 each).
Each of these tables joins together to form that data that I need by the 'USER_ID' field.   What is the easiest way to select this without duplicating the "USER_ID" field 3x?  I don't want to have to type out 'select table1.col1.....table3.col500'

my current query:

```
select table1.*, table2.*, table3.*
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on table1.user_id  = table2.user_id
JOIN table3 on table1.user_id =  table3.user_id
```

I'd like to do some sort of 'except table2.user_id, table3.user_id' in the select portion of the statement so I don't see this column there 3x...

Comment: No there is no such option in SQL. You have to type the columns you want. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+select+all+except+one+column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think this can be done using dynamic SQL, but this might be out of scope for the OP.

Comment: why dont you create the table with all columns and later drop the column  that you dont want

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is not a duplicate of the question you referenced. That question is about excluding a specific column (any) and this one is to exclude the join column that has a common name. In Postgres you can do that without dynamic sql with `select * from t1 join t2 using (colname)`

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  @AlexYes in MySQL this is not an option, perhaps it is in Postgres.  Let the OP clarify his database and then we can reopen this question if necessary.